# Get App Version and Build

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app but the iOS versions don't seem to be displaying correctly.

I set the `info.plist` to Version: 0.0 and Build: 9 but in the app it displays as Version 1.5.174 and Build 674

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SocialNetwork.iOS.Version_iOS))]
namespace SocialNetwork.iOS
{
public class Version_iOS : IAppVersion
{
    public string GetVersion()
    {
        return NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleShortVersionString").ToString();
    }
    public int GetBuild()
    {
        return int.Parse(NSBundle.MainBundle.ObjectForInfoDictionary("CFBundleVersion").ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

IAppVersion is simply

```
public interface IAppVersion
{
    string GetVersion();
    int GetBuild();
}
```

and I get the value using

```
public static string AppVersion = DependencyService.Get<IAppVersion>().GetVersion();
    public static int AppBuild = DependencyService.Get<IAppVersion>().GetBuild();
```

Comment: Make sure you delete the debug app from the simulator/device and perform a clean/build/debug session again. (note: the CFBundleVersion should be 3 numbers in dot notification (1.2.3)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am using Xamarin Live Player to test it on my iPhone so it is clean every time.

Comment: Xamarin Live Player is going to use its own info.plist, debug it on a simulator/device without live player....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SHARED**

*declaration:*

```
public interface IYourName
{
    string GetAppVersion();
}
```

*usage:*

```
 var AppVersion = DependencyService.Get<IYourName>().GetAppVersion();
```

**IOS**

```
    //****************************************************
    class YourNameHelpers : IYourName
    //****************************************************
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        public string GetAppVersion()
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        {    
            return NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary[new NSString("CFBundleVersion")].ToString();    
        }
    }
```

**Android**

```
    //****************************************************
    class YourNameHelpers : IYourName
    //****************************************************
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        public string GetAppVersion()
        //-------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            Context context = Forms.Context;
            PackageManager manager = context.PackageManager;
            PackageInfo info = manager.GetPackageInfo(context.PackageName, 0);
            return info.VersionName;
        }
    }
```